# Possible to merge or nest ES6 imports?

Tags: javascript, import, merge, ecmascript-6

Many modern JavaScript libraries are updating from monoliths to modularized npm packages; a couple of examples are [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized) and [d3](https://github.com/d3/).

This is great in terms of keeping build sizes down, but makes for a bit of awkwardness with imports. When loading the entire library, I write:

```
import d3 from 'd3';

let csv = d3.csv()...
let xScale = d3.scale()...
```

When loading individual modules instead of the whole package, I write:

```
import d3_scale from 'd3-scale';
import d3_request from 'd3-request';

let csv = d3_request.csv()...
let xScale = d3.scale.scaleLinear()...
```

Is there a syntax that would allow me to merge my imports so I can make all the function calls from each package off of a single object (e.g. `d3.csv()`, `d3.scaleLinear()`)?

Comment: What would be gained by having them all on the same object? Keeping independent things separate is kind of the point.

Comment: Why do you "*have to write...*"? You can import the whole package

Comment: @Amit as I explained in my question, I don't want to import all of `d3` because it's a large package and I can keep my build size down by importing only a subset of it.

Comment: @loganfsmyth a lot of d3's functions are used in tandem for common operations (e.g. rendering a chart), despite existing across separate modules. They exist in separate namespaces because of how they're bundled for npm, but all feel like part of the same library (and this is historically how d3 code has been written).

Comment: Right, but doesn't having a prefix like in your second example accomplish exactly that common association? Mashing them together into one object makes it impossible to know if you've forgotten to import and merge the functions you're trying to use, for instance. Same object => same library seems to be a mapping you've decided on, that I'd disagree with.

Comment: @loganfsmyth fair enough. This is mainly for convenience, and I can imagine situations in which it could be a bad idea. For example, that merge would overwrite methods of the same name in different namespaces. So, it's not a solution I'd want for all cases, but works for my current case.

Comment: You didn't explain in the question that you don't want to import all of d3. You wrote that "*Instead of writing...*" [you] "*have to write...*" which is wrong. You can import the whole package, but apparently you don't want to. And if that's the case, then I don't understand what it is that you do want.

Comment: @Amit updated to reflect my intent.

Answer (score 14):

As I was writing the question I figured out the answer. Self-rubber-ducking.

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) looks pretty decent here:

```
import * as d3_request from 'd3-request';
import * as d3_scale from 'd3-scale';
const d3 = {
    ...d3_request,
    ...d3_scale
};

d3.csv('path/to.csv', (error, data) => {
    let xScale = d3.scale()...
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to format this better? What's with the double-slash?

Comment: It is `const d3 = Object.assign({}, d3_request, d3_scale)`. In ES6 spreads are for iterables, and objects aren't the ones. [Object spreads](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) is stage 2 proposal.

Comment: @estus That's ok, I'm not looking for an ES6-specific answer, I'm looking for an answer that works in my build pipeline (Babel.js). So ES7 options work for me. But please feel free to write that up as a separate answer and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to do it like this

Create a file d3-modules.js:

```
export * from 'd3-request';
export * from 'd3-scale';
```

And then import that file where you need it:

```
import * as d3 from "./d3-modules.js";
```

It's actually how d3 are doing it themselves: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/635d44786dd4322d0c89dd98546bff91d7cce0fe/index.js